# Correlation in Apache Spark and groupBy with Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, correlation

I'm new in Python and Apache Spark, and try to understand, how function "pyspark.sql.functions.corr (val1, val2)" works.

I have big dataframe with auto brand, age and price. I want to get correlation between age and price for each auto brand.

I have 2 solutions:

```
//get all brands    
get_all_maker = data.groupBy("brand").agg(F.count("*").alias("counts")).collect()

for row in get_all_maker:
    print(row["brand"],": ",data.filter(data["brand"]==row["brand"]).corr("age","price"))
```

This solution is slow, because I use "corr" a lot of times.

So I tried to do it with one aggregation:

```
get_all_maker_corr = data.groupBy("brand").agg(
    F.count("*").alias("counts"),
    F.corr("age","price").alias("correlation")).collect()

for row in get_all_maker_corr:
    print(row["brand"],": ",row["correlation"])
```

If I try to compare results, they are different. But why?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with simple examples. Here I generate simple data frame:

```
d = [
    {'name': 'a', 'age': 1, 'price': 2},
    {'name': 'a', 'age': 2, 'price': 4},

    {'name': 'b', 'age': 1, 'price': 1},
    {'name': 'b', 'age': 2, 'price': 2}
]
b = spark.createDataFrame(d)
```

Let's test two methods:

```
#first version
get_all_maker = b.groupBy("name").agg(F.count("*").alias("counts")).collect()

print("Correlation (1st)") 
for row in get_all_maker:
    print(row["name"],"(",row["counts"],"):",b.filter(b["name"] == row["name"]).corr("age","price"))

#second version
get_all_maker_corr = b.groupBy("name").agg(
    F.count("*").alias("counts"),
    F.corr("age","price").alias("correlation")).collect()

print("Correlation (2nd)") 

for row in get_all_maker_corr:
    print(row["name"],"(",row["counts"],"):",row["correlation"])
```

Both of them bring me the same answer:

```
Correlation (1st)
b ( 2 ): 1.0
a ( 2 ): 1.0
```

Let's add another entry to data frame with None-value:

```
d = [
    {'name': 'a', 'age': 1, 'price': 2},
    {'name': 'a', 'age': 2, 'price': 4},
    {'name': 'a', 'age': 3, 'price': None},

    {'name': 'b', 'age': 1, 'price': 1},
    {'name': 'b', 'age': 2, 'price': 2}
]
b = spark.createDataFrame(d)
```

In first version you will get these results:

```
Correlation (1st)
b ( 2 ): 1.0
a ( 3 ): -0.5
```

and the second version bring you other results:

```
Correlation (2nd)
b ( 2 ): 1.0
a ( 3 ): 1.0
```

I think, that dataframe.filter with corr-function set None-value to 0-value.

And dataframe.groupBy with F.corr-function in agg-function will ignore None-value.

So, two these methods are not equal. I don't know, if this is a bug or a feature of the Spark system, but just in case you want to count correlation value, the data should be used only without None-value.